# How do you send a variable to Azure Event Hubs using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

If I have a variable containing the temperature value, how can I send it using ServiceBusService.send_event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are consuming it on the other side of event hubs. If you are using [Azure Stream Analytics](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/) you must make sure that the format you are sending to event hubs is either json, csv, or [arvo](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html).

If you have a variable, it would be simple enough to create a dictionary, serialize it using Python's [json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and send the resulting string.  Example:

```
from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService
import json;

sbs = ServiceBusService("your_namespace",
                        shared_access_key_name="your_policy_name",
                        shared_access_key_value="your_policy_secret")

# build dictionary and send value
temp = {'DeviceId': 'dev-01', 'Temperature': str(i)}
sbs.send_event('woodstove2', json.dumps(temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have created a ServiceBus namespace for EventHub. If not, please refer to "Create an Event Hub" section of the article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/.

You will get ServiceBus SAS name & key in the Service Bus Configure page as below.

[image]

If the service bus does not contain an event hubs, you can create it manually via clicking the tab "event hubs", or create it by using Python SDK.

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

servns = '<service_bus _namespace>'
key_name = '<service_bus_sas_keyname>'  # SharedAccessKeyName from Azure portal
key_value = '<service_bus_sas_key>'  # SharedAccessKey from Azure portal
sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace=servns,
                        shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                        shared_access_key_value=key_value) # Create a ServiceBus Service Object
flag = sbs.create_event_hub('<event_hub_name>') # Create a Event Hub for the ServiceBus. If it exists then return true, else return false
print(flag)
event_data = '<event_data>'
sbs.send_event('<event_hub_name>', event_data) # Send event data to your Event Hub, like real-time temperature data
```

According to your scene, you can serialize event data to JSON string, CSV String with header as jsturtevant said.

For temperature example:

1. JSON

event_data = '{"deviceId": "dev01", "time": "2015-08-24 12:34:45", "temperature": 30.0 }'

2. CSV

event_data = 'deviceId,time,temperature\ndev01,2015-08-24 12:34:45,30.0'

For more information about ServiceBus Python SDK, you can refer to the part - "Usage" of the link "README.rst" https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-servicebus.